# How to SQL Sum on a field and have a different field in group by section?

Tags: sql-server, select, group-by, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have a table like this: (Please note that Names are not unique and can be repeated, while Personal_ID is unique).

```
ID    SourceID     Personal_ID     Name     NumberOfPurchases 
1      4            1001           Alex           10
2      2            1002           Sara            5
3      4            1001           Alex            12
4      1            1003           Mina            200
5      2            1002           Sara            20  
6      2            1001           Alex            64
```

Now what need to do is to get the total sum of Number of purchases each person had based on given the SourceID. So that we have the results for `sourceId = 4`  as:

```
        Name        Total Number of Purchases
 1.     Alex                 22
```

And for SourceID = 2

```
        Name        Total Number of Purchases
1.      Alex                 64
2.      Sara                 25
```

For this I came up with something like this:

```
SELECT Name,Sum(NumberOfPurchases) AS Total
FROM    tblTEST
GROUP BY (Personal_ID)
HAVING (SOURCEID = @id)
```

but this is apparently wrong. I am stuck here, if I add other fields to the `group-by clause` the result would be completely different and if I don't, this select command wont work. How can I achieve such a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that the problem here is that you have `Name` in your `SELECT` clause, but you're grouping on `Personal_ID`. It might help if you add `Name` explicitly to your `GROUP BY` clause as well. If all is well, `Name` will be functionally determined by `Personal_ID` anyway.

And you should also put the filter on SourceID in the `WHERE` clause like [Lucero says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14955879/249353). So your query should look like this:

```
SELECT   Name
         ,Sum(NumberOfPurchases) AS Total
FROM     tblTEST
WHERE    SOURCEID = @id
GROUP BY Personal_ID, Name;
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/da5e2/4).

To clear things up: if you use an aggregation function like `SUM()`, all *other* things in your `SELECT` clause should also be in your `GROUP BY` clause. But you do not want to group only on `Name`, because it is not unique in your case. That is why you have both `Personal_ID` **and** `Name` in your `GROUP BY` clause. The query will not execute when `Name` is missing in the `GROUP BY`. And you're adding `Personal_ID` to make sure not all Sara's are put in a big Sara-group, but are grouped according to `Personal_ID`.

Comment: Thankyou very much but Names are not unique , so they can repeated , so that query wont give me the expected result!

Comment: `HAVING` compares only results of aggregate function calls with some value ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180199.aspx)). This won't compile.

Comment: @Hossein: but the combination of the Personal_ID and the Name **is** unique, right? Or do you want different Alexes in an _Alex_ group and Sara's in the _Sara_ group??

Comment: @IvanG: you're right, changed it accordingly. At first I just looked at the missing `Name` in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Thanks Josien :) Yes that combination is also unique and feasible

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
SELECT Name, SUM(NumberOfPurchases) AS Total
FROM tblTEST
WHERE (SourceID = @id)
GROUP BY Name
```

Note: The `WHERE` filters *before* grouping, and `HAVING` filters *after* grouping.

Comment: Thank you but names are not unique, Thats why im using Personal_ID to get each persons purchases uniquely

Comment: `Name` column is a poor candidate for grouping, names aren't unique. If you had another user named 'Alex' with different `Personal_ID` all of their purchases would be summed together although there are two different persons.

Comment: @IvanG, while your argument is true, I followed what columns the OP selected in the original query. Since the ID was never selected, a `GROUP BY` with both would yield multiple rows with the identical (indistinguishible) name and a number of purchases, which is nonsense as well. My answer was adressing the filtering aspect.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
SELECT  names.Name
        , names.Personal_ID
        , grouped.Total
FROM    (
            SELECT  SourceID
                    , Personal_ID
                    , SUM(NumberOfPurchases) AS Total
            FROM    tblTEST
            GROUP BY 
                    SourceID, Personal_ID
) grouped
JOIN    (

        SELECT  DISTINCT
                Personal_ID
                , Name
        FROM    tblTEST
) names ON      names.Personal_ID = grouped.Personal_ID
WHERE           SourceID = @id
```

Here is an **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/78a3e/5/1)**

Among test data I added another record that contains person named 'Alex', now there are two persons with same name which shows that grouping cannot be performed using `Name` column since it is not unique. I also added `Personal_ID` in the select list so that people with same names could be distinguished.

Comment: :Thank you very much,That is very great , i was sceptical on which one to choose as answer and since the Josiens solution was briefer i chose that one.I also liked that SQL Fiddle link of yours it was great.All in all i just wanted to show you my deep appreciation on your help ;) Thank you again:)

Comment: You're welcome:) Josien's solution is good and efficient since it's grouped by `Personal_ID` and `Name`. Only one name is connected to one person's ID so it's simple and it works as expected.